# Recursive Call in controller Lightning

Tags: lightning, controller

I want to make recursive call in js controller on my lightning component.. Following is my js controller but I am getting an error as

> 'callback' must be a valid Function

```
check : function(component, event, helper) {
    var str = component.get('v.message');
    if(str == null){
        str = '';
    }
    $A.getCallback(helper.check(component,str),1200);
}
```

ControllerHelper Code :

```
check : function(cmp,a) {
    var msg = 'Welcome to Dairy Startup';
    if(a.length < msg.length){
        a = msg.substring(0,a.length + 1);
        cmp.set('v.message',a);
    }
}
```

How Can I make recursive call to helper method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're actually *calling* the function, but instead what you want to do is *bind* it to get a function. That looks like this:

```
$A.getCallback(helper.check.bind(helper,component,str));
```

Where the first parameter is the "this" variable (the helper), and the parameters thereafter are function parameters.

You can read more about [binding over on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind).

You also are presumably trying to create a delay, so you need to use setTimeout:

```
setTimeout($A.getCallback(helper.check.bind(helper,component,str)), 1200);
```

Comment: Thank You very much..That was very well explained.. Can you please tell me how to recursively call the above method?I tried setInterval($A.getCallback(helper.check.bind(helper,component,str)), 1200)) but it is not working

Comment: @AkkiGupta You're binding the value "str", so if you're trying to basically do an animation, move the part where you get the v.message attribute to the check function.

Comment: @sfdcfox Is this called recursion? I thought “recursion” means function calling itself. I have not studied computer science in college, so I could be wrong and want to confirm.

Comment: @javanoob I didn't bother to correct the terminology, but you're right, a function calling itself is a recursive function. What the OP probably should have done is set the time out for the next call to check within check, thus making it a recursive function of sorts (though asynchronously).